# Graphic novel where teenager is confronted by a man with robotic arm, a girl and a "pig man"

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading this graphic novel in my public library but it is no longer there. The book or its cover art was somehow related to a slaughterhouse. I know it’s really weird and strange, but I was fascinated with it for some reason and just want to find it. It was written in English; I read it about 5-6 years ago and I have no idea how old it was.

The first book in the series (if it was one) focused on a teenager. In the beginning at some point he went to some sort of store or restaurant with some other teenagers; and then it gets fuzzy, but later at a skatepark or somewhere he is confronted by a man with a robotic arm (and maybe more robotic body parts), a girl, and I think there was a guy with a pig mask or a pig man.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)